# Implementing css to parent element only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on a navigation menu where any menu item doesn't fit onto available space get appended onto a hidden unordered list(`ul`) which can be accessed through a toggle button. What I would like to achieve is to display `Group-1`, `Group-2`...as `inline-block` without affecting css of child elements.I am trying to use below css;

```
.hidden-link{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

However when I use this line it changes all children element's property to show in a row rather that in a table format. I have tried jquery as well but no win.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.hidden-links").children().css("display","inline-block");
});
```

e.g

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class='hidden-links hidden'>
        <li>Group1
            <ul class ="flash">
                <li>item-1</li>
                <li>item-1</li>
                <li>item-1</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Group2
            <ul class ="flash">
                <li>item-1</li>
                <li>item-1</li>
                <li>item-1</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Group3
            <ul class ="flash">
                <li>item-1</li>
                <li>item-1</li>
                <li>item-1</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your html is invalid. You can use only `li` in root of `ul`.

Comment: UL cannot be direct child of other UL

Comment: Sorry there were some errors now amended

Comment: Is  there a way to achieve this using jquery so that only css can be applied on the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you only need to select the direct children of the menu.

Then this is all you need.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.hidden-links > li").css("display","inline-block");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Paulie it did work when used you specified selector in css :-)
ul.hidden-links > li{
 display: inline-block;
}

Answer (score 0):

If you want each element do be shown on a separate row, then you should be using `display: block` instead of `inline-block'.

More info on `inline-block` here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple css tricks to tackle this problem. Styled both ul in different css.

```
.hidden-links li{
  display: inline-block;
 }
 li .flash li{
  display: block;
 }
```